# Where i can find default.xml file in android source code 4.2.2.(Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, native

I want to DISABLE the auto-rotation screen value as default.Please tell me how the android will get the default values.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want to force the screen orientation in portrait?

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Prohibiting orientation changes is not a good practice. Nonetheless, you can achieve this directly within the [`activity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) tag of your [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html):

```
 android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                     "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```